# SQL22223N creating database with DB2 Express C for Windows

Tags: db2, coexistence

I am having problems trying to create a database with DB2 Express C (v9.7).

I already have a another version of DB2 installed on my system:

```
Product: DB2 Connect Enterprise Edition 
Version: 8.2
Copy: DB2COPY1
Instance: DB2
```

I understand that it is possible to have coexistence.

Express C has seemingly installed OK on my laptop, and I am able to use the Sample Database without a problem. I created new copy DB2COPY2, and new instance DB2_01.

I've installed it as a DB2ADMN.

When I try and create a database I get the error:

SQL22223N The Instance "DB2_01" does not exist on host "host name".

It is saying that the instance does not exist on the host. Which is strange because I installed it locally as a DB2ADMN.

Comment: Are you doing this thru the Command Editor or Control Center? Can you give the command you issued when getting the error. I notice there are two empty double quotes at the end of the error after the word "host". Seems like there should be a host name listed there if you are connected to one.

Comment: Yes there is a host name there, sorry that's a typo. This happens when trying to create a database through Command Centre. I use Command Centre > Control Centre > Create Database. This is when I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Coexistence is supported. You have to open correct CLP version, and

```
set db2instance=db2_01
db2cc
```

and then it should work. If it doesn't you have to probably [uncatalog and re-catalog](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21214146) your node and databases.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried running those commands but I get the error: SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist. Also, I'll be totally honest with you, I've no idea what a "node" is in Db2 terms.

Comment: @Paul Node translates to server. The tools you are using are legacy stuff, and they use these directories for servers and databases, containing connection information for them. Now you managed to tell DB2 to use the correct directories, but likely you don't have anything to connect to. You will have to tell DB2 about your servers (nodes), instances and databases - just like in the link I gave. TBH Windows and use of those type-2 legacy tools is hellish for beginners... :(